# Automated mail process - how to get started?

Tags: api, email, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I try to automate a mail process: somebody sends me a mail, I extract info from the mail and do some stuff, then send out a new email to a third person. The automated process should happen silently in the background without my intervention (typing in my password, click some button, etc.)

The email system: O365, sign in is redirected to corp login page, with Two Factor Authentication. I'm not the administrator of O365.

I think some API may be useful. However I'm completely new to this area and feel overwhelmed by all the offerings: EWS (Exchange Web Service), RESTful API, or any SDK? Also, do non-administrators have sufficient permission to create their own apps? (I have used some third party mail apps, and obviously they do not have approval from my admins. But my app differs in that it should not require my input.)

Preferably I want to script in Python, but C# is also fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*The question is a little bit to broad to be answered here. So the answer I could give you is only a general one:*

So if you need to interact with an system which isn´t under your control / which you do not administrate (e.g. Cloud Services) you might wish to build something on IMAP / Pop3 (if you are allowed to use them to access emails. If you are only allowed to use Outlook via Web browser this would be no option). Fetch the emails via those protocols, perform your operation, then send out a new emails via SMTP. However your administrator might have locked that due to security reasons. The same might apply here to EWS, so you need to check with him which options are allowed for your account.

You also might find various solutions and howtos using IMPA/POP3 + SMTP so you do not need to start from scratch and might be the easiest way for you.

*Offtopic: Another option which might be working for you is an AutoIT script. But I would consider that as offtopic.*